# How to add a value at the end of JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$resultado = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
echo '[';
for ($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($resultado);$i++) {
echo ($i > 0 ? ',' : '').json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($resultado));
}
echo ']';
```

Need is Insert $SLUG the end of Json so it is the same object

```
{
tabela:valor
slug:valor
}
```

tried to array_push() but without success;

Comment: Please use english, this is international page ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode **final result,** not each row:

```
$array = array();
for ($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($resultado);$i++) {
    $array[] = mysqli_fetch_object( $resultado );
}

$array[] = $SLUG;                                 # <----------------

echo json_encode( $array );
```

Different approach:

```
$array = array();
for ($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($resultado);$i++) {
    $array[] = mysqli_fetch_object( $resultado );
}

$final = array( 'tabela' => $array(), 'slug' => $SLUG ); 
echo json_encode( $final );
```

Comment: what is Insert $SLUG the end of Json ?

Comment: after `for` loop, simply do `$array[] = $SLUG;` before encoding JSON (see edited answer)

Comment: Must be the same object.
way it will be done the LOOP and the end of all the LOOP is inserted $ SLUG
[{Table: value}, {slug: value}]
Each loop has to be inserted $ SLUG

I want you so
[{Table: Value, slug: value}]

Comment: This is not a free code service. Above you see a detailed example: it is not so hard figure-it how to modify it to obtain desired result...

Comment: `$array[] = array( 'table' => mysqli_fetch_object(), 'slug' => $SLUG );` ;)